# iOS 12.2 Control Center Remote Control Finds no TVs

Tags: iphone, ios, appletv, control-center, remote.app

We have two Apple TV 4s and a number of iOS devices. After the iOS 12.2 update, my iPhone XS would not find the TV called LIVING ROOM but would work with PORCH just fine. I uninstalled the Remote app, and restarted my Apple TV and my phone. Now, my iPhone does not see any Apple TVs in the house, even after reinstalling the Apple TV Remote app (which *does* work without any problems).

LIVING ROOM shows up just fine on my iPad. Both TVs show up on my wife's iPhone X.

I am open to suggestions for further troubleshooting that are short of restoring my iPhone from backup. I would prefer not to reset iPhone Networking Settings unless somebody is pretty sure that is likely to fix the issue.

Comment: I wonder if the space with "LIVING ROOM" is the issue. Can you change that to "LIVINGROOM" or perhaps "LIVING_ROOM"?

Comment: It can't see PORCH, and the other iPhone running 12.2 sees LIVING ROOM just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t say for certain which of these mattered but here is what led to this bing fixed for me.

1. Update to iOS 12.3
2. Update AppleTV to tvOS 12.3
3. Reset Network Settings on iPhone
4. Add AppleTV to a room in Home.app
5. Delete all paired “extra” remotes on AppleTV (apps and other devices)
6. Give iPhone new, not-previously used name
7. Re-pair iPhone Remote app (which, remember had worked this whole time) to Apple TV

I suspect it was steps 5-7 that were all I needed, and I’m bummed that I nuked my Network Settings, but the Control Cemter widget works for me now.